# Ksh : How to connect to sqlplus without using tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ksh

I try to connect to sqlplus from ksh without using tnsnames.ora but that does not work as I would.

Here's what I try :

```
DBLOGIN="user/password@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.17.33)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MYTESTSID)))'"

SQLPLUS="/etc/sqlplus"

CONNECT=`${SQLPLUS} -S ${DBLOGIN} <<-EOF
SET ECHO OFF;
select count(*) from mytable;
EOF`

echo "$CONNECT"
```

This should return the number of rows in mytable but that returns nothing so I think that the connection cannot be established...

Comment: your question was my answer

Answer (score 10):

You can also use :

```
sqlplus USER/PASSWORD@//hostName:port/SID
```

Comment: It does not work when SID is pointing to an Oracle database link

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Easy Connect](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm#i498306)

Comment: That works now. I had not the ";" before the "EOF" on my local script (but I had it posted lol)...